# Vue3 works with unpkg but not with npm + webpack

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, browser, vuejs3

I'm trying to set up Vue3 so that I can use it via npm + webpack. For some reason the component does not get mounted and no error is shown. If I instead use unpkg it works. How can I make the npm + webpack option work?

---

I have `"vue": "^3.1.5"` in my `package.json` and the following webpack config:

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    provider:  './src/components/provider.js',
    requester: './src/components/requester.js',
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  },
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/../public`,
    filename: '[name].js',
  }
}
```

requester.js:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'

createApp({
  template: `
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>Números recibidos</h2>
        {{ receivedNumbers }}
        <ul>
          <li v-for="n in receivedNumbers">{{ n }}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      receivedNumbers: [1,2,3],
      numberRequestIsOpen: false,
    }
  },
}).mount('#requester-component');
```

requester.html

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>requester</h1>

    <div id="requester-component"></div>
    <script src="requester.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

resulting html

```html
    <h1>requester</h1>

    <div id="requester-component" data-v-app=""><!----></div>
    <script src="requester.js"></script>
```

---

In the other hand, if I add `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>` in the `head` tag of my html and change the js to:

```js
Vue.createApp({
  //
}).mount('#requester-component');
```

then the resulting html is

```html
    <h1>requester</h1>

    <div id="requester-component" data-v-app=""><div><div><h2>Números recibidos</h2> [
  1,
  2,
  3
] <ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul></div></div></div>
    <script src="requester.js"></script>
```

which is the expected output.

---

Link to the [repo](https://github.com/ffigari/preguntitas/tree/8979b88998eb6d936a14acf2564e2426584a98c0/requester-provider) in case it helps to play around. Last commit adds the unpkg has, and the previous one has the npm version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/4275

> In order to use the functionality of the vue.js template, you need to load the finished package with the compiler and runtime, but vue.js by default loads the runtime only version, so you need to explicitly specify the version (vue.esm-bundler.js)

Adding

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js'
    }
  }
```

solved the issue.